# Language certification and the usage of terms like appropriate vs correct vs legal

Tags: java, terminology

I'm studying for the SCJP (inanely over-technical java certification) 
In my readings, I'm running into questions telling me to judge "appropriate", "correct", or "legal" usage of something. I know these are not all the same, but I'm unsure of what the difference is.
Can someone mention exactly what
1. appropriate used is
2. correct usage is
3. legal usage is

Comment: "Just because you can, it doesn't mean you should." Legal => you can do it. Appropriate => you *should* do it. Two different things. You can concatenate to a string variable in loop. Totally legal. More *appropriate* is to use a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Appropiate -> There are alternatives but this is the best
Correct    -> There are no alternatives
Legal      -> You can do it ( it doesn't matter if it is appropiate or correct )
```